# Print double array by looping

Tags: c, arrays

So this is puzzling me.  I have a two dimensional array and when I loop to print the first pointers array, it does not give me the same correct information, but if I call each specific place it gives me the correct information.

it has a lot of debugging printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void input_data(char string[2000], int *arr[51]);
double do_math(int *arr);
void print_data(int **arr);
void make_line(int *result, int num, int score, int weight, int late);

int main(){
   char input[2000];
   char line[100];
   int *grade_book[51];

   while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)){
      printf("input given: %s", line);
      strcat(input, line);
   }

   printf("input = %s", input);
   input_data(input, grade_book);

   print_data(grade_book);


   return(1);
}

void input_data(char input[2000], int *arr[51]){
   int data[4], result[4];
   int stat, penalty, drop_num, total, r, num, score, weight, late;
   char status, t;

   sscanf(input, " %d %d %c %d", &penalty, &drop_num, &status, &total);
   stat = 0;
   if(status == 'Y'){
      stat = 1;
   }
   printf("penalty: %d, drop_num: %d, status: %c, total = %d\n", penalty, drop_num, status, total);
   data[0] = penalty;
   data[1] = drop_num;
   data[2] = stat;
   data[3] = total;
   arr[0] = data;
   printf("%d %d %d %d", arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2], arr[0][3]);

   for(r = 1; r < total; r++){
      sscanf(input, " %d %c %d %c %d %c %d", &num, &t,
       &score, &t, &weight, &t, &late);
       make_line(result, num, score, weight, late);
       arr[num] = result;
   }
}
```

The output is

```
input given: 10 0 Y
input given: 2
input given: 2, 80, 40, 0
input given: 1, 100, 60, 0
input = 10 0 Y
2
2, 80, 40, 0
1, 100, 60, 0
penalty: 10, drop_num: 0, status: Y, total = 2
10 0 1 2
10 0 1 2
0:10 1:0 2:4196792 3:0
```

Clearly in the loop the 3rd call is a pointer, but I have no clue as to which and why it is giving me this output.

Comment: How is `print_data` called?

Comment: this code works fine for me

Comment: We still cannot compile and run this code. We need to see the implementation of `input_data()`. I'd be willing to bet that `gradebook[0]` points to a temporary value on the stack.

Comment: This can't possibly be your output. Where are all the `input given:` and `input = ` things that your code claims to print?

Comment: Surprizingly enough it is my output. the code isnt finished but i have just uploaded the whole thing

Comment: Here's your problem -----> `arr[0] = data;` and `arr[num] = result;` Neither `result` nor `data` survive past the end of `input_data()`, so you're just left with bad pointers.

Comment: @sharth: Looks like you'd win that bet.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in the code, the most glaring is the setting of pointers in arr[] to point to a field on the stack in the function input_data().  Upon return to the caller, those pointers are pointing to trash.  I would start by re-defining grade_book[] to have 4 integers in each entry and moving the 4 integers rather than setting a pointer in the calling function to a called functions stack entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `input_data()`, you have:

```
int data[4], result[4];
```

followed by:

```
arr[0] = data;
```

and:

```
arr[num] = result;
```

Both `data` and `result` are automatic arrays, which means they will be destroyed when `input_data()` returns. So all those pointers you're putting into `arr` will point to invalid locations once your function returns.

Even if it worked, the way you currently have it written, every element of `arr` except the first will all end up pointing to the same location, which is probably not want you want, otherwise you could get away with a 2 element array, rather than a 51 element array.

Instead, you should dynamically allocate arrays for your `arr` elements to point to.